# Implement a Compass for Cross Platform (Android & iOS)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to implement a compass in Xamarin.Forms like the one shown in the image below. Any ideas how to implement it?  Thanks.

[image: compass]

Comment: Hi Shivam. Please read this section https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting the question in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@partic you have right!
i have do it by plugin.compass with pcl :-

On top of the rotating background, add another Image for the pointer. On top of the pointer, add 2 labels.

For the 1st label, it will display the cardinal directions. You can use the following C# code to calculate the cardinal directions:

string[] directions = new string[] { "N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW", "N" };

first one for the design :-

for the MVVM file :-

CrossCompass.Current.Start();                 if (CrossCompass.Current.IsSupported)                 {                      CrossCompass.Current.CompassChanged += CompassChangedEvent;                  }
event for compasschanged :-

void CompassChangedEvent(object sender,CompassChangedEventArgs  e)               {               GlobalPropertiseAndMethod.compassDegree=Math.Round(e.Heading).ToString() + "\u00B0 ";             GlobalPropertiseAndMethod.compassValue = e.Heading;             _blaffrGoViewModel.CompassDegree = GlobalPropertiseAndMethod.compassDegree;             GetDirectionWithDegree(Math.Round(GlobalPropertiseAndMethod.compassValue));             _blaffrGoViewModel.Rotation = -(GlobalPropertiseAndMethod.compassValue);               }  
set data on the binding context :-

public void GetDirectionWithDegree(double azimuth)         {             try             {                 if (azimuth >= 0)                 {                     CompassDirection = directions[((int)azimuth) / 45];                 }                 else                 {                     CompassDegree = "Sorry, Compass is not working.....";                 }             }             catch (Exception ex)             {                 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);             }         }

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `Image` for the background of the compass.  Set the `Rotation` of the background image in C#.  You want the rotation to go anticlockwise when the reading of your compass increases:

```
// "heading" is a double variable that stores the reading of your compass
backgroundImage.Rotation = -heading
```

On top of the rotating background, add another `Image` for the pointer.  On top of the pointer, add 2 labels.

For the 1st label, it will display the cardinal directions.  You can use the following C# code to calculate the cardinal directions:

```
var directions = new string[] { "NE", "SE", "SW", "NW", "NE" };

directionLabel.Text = directions[((int)heading) / 90];
```

For the 2nd label, it will display the heading. You can use the following C# code to set the text of the 2nd label:

```
// assuming variable "heading" is a double
headingLabel.Text = ((int)heading).toString() + "°";
```